# SharePoint Designer, create "Birthday" item that reoccurs every Year?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, recurring-events

Has anyone created reoccurring tasks using SharePoint Designer (SharePoint Online)? Is it possible?

I can set "Recurrence" to "Yes", but it gives "rendering error" on the form. Not sure how to set "Repeat every year" option in SPD.

Or is there a way to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Finally created it programmatically, the snippet with JSOM is here:

[JSOM, Calendar Recurring task: "Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215859/jsom-calendar-recurring-task-item-does-not-exist-it-may-have-been-deleted-by)

or example using REST:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361200/how-to-set-recurrencedata-values-in-sharepoint-calendar-list-using-javascript

You can create calendar item manually, then use SharePoint Manager to find  setting in item properties, and then provide this  setting in Your JSOM/REST code